# Difference between array indexOf() and string indexOf() causing issue with versions

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript, mocha.js, indexof

I have this array of versions in my Node applicaiton:

```
skipVersions = ['3.10', '3.11', '3.12', '3.13.1', '3.13.2']
```

I'm using this code to check which versions can be skipped:

```
if (skipVersion(version, skipVersions))
  this.skip 'Skipping version'


skipVersion = (version, skipVersions) ->
    (v for v in skipVersions when v.indexOf(version) > -1).length > 0
```

My problem is that versions may appear in the format x.x.x eg. 3.12.2. I would want this to skip under the version 3.12 check but it isn't happening. It seems there is a difference between `indexOf()` for an array and for a string. With that in mind, how do I do my chekk?

Comment: Doing `indexOf()` on a string will try and find occurrences of a **character** instead of the whole word being searched.

Comment: @jom Uh, no, it searches for the whole argument string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing this:

```
skipVersion = (version, skippedVersions) ->
   if version != undefined
      (v for v in skippedVersions when version.indexOf(v) > -1).length > 0
```